# Probabilistic Independent Events Example

Tags: probability

A given a random experiment, A and B are two **independent** events such that:

ℙ (A) = 1/5

ℙ (B) = 1/9

How can we calculate ℙ [A | (A ∪ B)] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Write that $\mathbb{P}(A | (A \cup B)) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A\cap(A\cup B))}{\mathbb{P}(A\cup B)} = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A)}{\mathbb{P}(A\cup B)}$ and conclude by using independence to compute both numerator and denominator.

Comment: Now how can I calculate ℙ (A ∩ B) and ℙ (A ∪ B) ?

Comment: @FranciscoMariaCalisto you only need to compute $\mathbb{P}(A \cup B) = \mathbb{P}(A) +\mathbb{P}(B) - \mathbb{P}(A \cap B)$ using independence. By definition of independence, you know that $\mathbb{P}(A|B) = \mathbb{P}(A)$, so what can you conclude?

Comment: ℙ (A ∩ B) is zero for independent events right?

Comment: @FranciscoMariaCalisto Not necessarily. Instead, use that $\mathbb{P}(A|B) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(B)}$.